# action url google home

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home

I wonder if there is a way that you can tell google home something when calling an action URL. Is there any information on how this can be relaized? So far I have not been able to find anything unfortunately.

Greetings
xs

Comment: Can you be more clear with the wording of your question ? I would recommend sharing 
            SYNC and QUERY payload for your issue at hand along with your requirement.

Comment: The question is actually quite simple to understand. I want google home (e.g. nest mini) to actively speak something when a certain url is called (e.g. https:\\ipFromGoogleNestMini\speakHello.html).

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available as part of the Smart Home ecosystem. As far as I know there is not a way of programmatically controlling the Assistant's voice responses on demand (eg. by passing a link).

However, I would recommend to also ask on the Nest Community page on speakers and displays to make sure: https://www.googlenestcommunity.com/t5/Speakers-and-Displays/bd-p/SpeakersDisplays